# SwiftUI updating toolbar item text between views

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to create a view which will allow the user to browse trough the application saved documents. The view should have on top navigation controls and on the same line should display the current folder name, a search box and a custom scroll view. The issue that I have is that when the ScrollView is presented once I enter in a directory the current folder name disappears from the screen.

```
import SwiftUI
import PDFKit

class FileViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentFolderName: String = "Documents"
}


struct FilesView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: FileViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            FileListView()
                .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                        Text("\(viewModel.currentFolderName)")
                            .font(.headline)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}

struct FileListView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: FileViewModel
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let folderURL: URL
    @State private var searchText: String = ""
    
    init(folderURL: URL? = nil) {
        if let url = folderURL {
            self.folderURL = url
        } else {
            self.folderURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // Search Field
            TextField("Search", text: $searchText)
                .padding(8)
                .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
                .cornerRadius(8)
                .padding(.horizontal)
            
            // Grid View
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 16), count: 3), spacing: 16) {
                    ForEach(fetchFiles(), id: \.self) { url in
                        if searchText.isEmpty || url.lastPathComponent.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) {
                            NavigationLink(
                                destination: destination(for: url)
                            ) {
                                VStack {
                                    if let isDirectory = try? url.resourceValues(forKeys: [.isDirectoryKey]).isDirectory, isDirectory == true {
                                        Image(systemName: "folder.fill")
                                            .resizable()
                                            .frame(width: 90, height: 60)
                                    } else {
                                        Image(systemName: "doc.fill")
                                            .resizable()
                                            .frame(width: 90, height: 60)
                                    }
                                    Text(url.lastPathComponent)
                                        .lineLimit(1)
                                        .font(.caption)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding()
            }
        }
        .onAppear() {
            viewModel.currentFolderName = folderName(from: folderURL)
            print("Folder URL: \(folderURL)")
        }
    }
    
    func folderName(from url: URL) -> String {
        return url.lastPathComponent
    }
    
    func fetchFiles() -> [URL] {
        do {
            let fileURLs = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: folderURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
            return fileURLs
        } catch {
            print("Error while fetching files: \(error)")
            return []
        }
    }
    
    func destination(for url: URL) -> some View {
        if let isDirectory = try? url.resourceValues(forKeys: [.isDirectoryKey]).isDirectory, isDirectory == true {
            return AnyView(FileListView(folderURL: url).environmentObject(viewModel))
        } else {
            let fileExtension = url.pathExtension
            switch fileExtension {
            case "pdf":
                return AnyView(PDFKitView(url: url))
            case "txt":
                if let content = try? String(contentsOf: url) {
                    return AnyView(Text(content))
                }
                return AnyView(Text("Cannot load file"))
            default:
                return AnyView(Text("File type not supported"))
            }
        }
    }

}

struct PDFKitView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let url: URL
    
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFKitView>) -> PDFView {
        let pdfView = PDFView()
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        return pdfView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: PDFView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFKitView>) {
        uiView.load(url: url)
    }
}

extension PDFView {
    func load(url: URL) {
        if let document = PDFDocument(url: url) {
            self.document = document
        }
    }
}

struct FilesView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FilesView()
            .environmentObject(FileViewModel())
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you declare your `FileViewModel` and pass it to the `FilesView()`. For example, do you use `@StateObject var viewModel = FileViewModel()`? Note `NavigationView` is deprecated, you shoud use `NavigationStack`